# trap raphael.js animation of circle inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I build two Raphael.js Objects into a `<div id="eyes"></div>`

```
var paper = Raphael('eyes', 200, 200);

        var left_eye = paper.circle(60, 40, 26);
        var right_eye = paper.circle(125, 40, 26);

        left_eye.attr("stroke", "#575757");
        left_eye.attr("stroke-width", 6 );

        right_eye.attr("stroke", "#575757");
        right_eye.attr("stroke-width", 6    );
```

I have an animation where two circles animate depending on mouse position:

```
jQuery('body').mousemove(function(evt) {

    var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
    var mouse_y = evt.pageY;

    //raphael object 1 and 2        
    left_eye.animate({cx:mouse_x/10},5); 
    right_eye.animateWith(left_eye, null, {cx:mouse_x/10+80}, 5);

    }
});
```

The problem is, since the div where both object are in has a fixed width and height. When I'm moving the mouse to far left or right, SVG object disappears like every element in a `overflow: hidden` div.

How can I trap the Element inside a div? Like having border the animation can't cross.

Example: [someone else made a similar fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCBwC/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use the solution in fiddle you posted? Cap the x and y with a max value.

Comment: @MattR I don't know why, because I tried it and it just works fine.